# There is a way to *exact* resize on-the-fly an Image Object in Plone?

Tags: plone, zope, image-scaling

Just for be clear, this method is not what i'm looking for:

```
<img tal:define="scale context/@@images"
 tal:replace="structure python: scale.scale('image', width=42, height=42).tag()" />
```

In fact this method resize an *ImageField*. I want to resize an *Image* object to a specific and exact resolution without ratio. 
Any way to do this ?

--edit--

The *Image* object for me is one of the items showed in portal_types on the ZMI.
In a few words i want the same behaviour of the code above, but on *Image* type.

Cheers,
Alessio

Comment: define "Image object" and "specific and exact resolution without ratio" please.

Comment: I have modified the question. I hope that helps!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Image objects contain an image field, which can be resized. But you cannot resize the image object itself, that wouldn't make any sense.  You can define any number of custom image resizes (which will affect the image fields in Image objects) in the control panel.  You can't resize images freely on the fly, though.

You can use an add-on product like ImageEditor (http://plone.org/products/products-imageeditor) to provide arbitrary image editing/resizing to end-users.  It's very useful, but may not be what you need.

Comment: That's true! Thanks, i had not thought of this.